# Expected value confused

Tags: probability, expected-value

An urn contains n + m balls, of which n are red and m are black. They are withdrawn from the urn, one at a time and without replacement. Let X be the number of red balls removed after the first but before the third black ball is chosen. Find the expected value of

I add every probability up like P(BBB)+P(BRBB)+P(BBRB)+…P(BRRRRRRBB)
Do we have easily way to do

Comment: Which probability distributions have you studied? For example, do you know about the binomial distribution or the hypergeometric distribution?